# Row and Column count of data grid in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Consider I have a data grid, I need to find the number of rows and coulmns in the data grid. How can I do this in C#?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `DataGrid.Items` property returns a `DataGridItemCollection` representing the `DataGridItems` in the DataGrid.

Each `DataGridItem` is representative of a single row in the rendered table. Also, the `DataGridItem` exposes a `Cells` property which represents the no. of tablecells (in other words, the columns) in the rendered table.

```
int rowCount = myGrid.Items.Count;

// Get the no. of columns in the first row.
int colCount = myGrid.Items[0].Cells.Count;
```

Answer (score 5):

DataGrids represent actual DataItems.

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

dg.Items.Count; //Number of Items...i.e. Rows;
dg.Items[0].Cells.Count; //Number of columns for that Items
```

Comment: +1 for reading my mind! This time, however, I was a few seconds quicker! :P

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to answer your question:

```
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
int rowCount = dataGrid.BindingContext[dataGrid.DataSource].Count;
```

or, if you know for sure the type of the DataSource:

```
int rowCount = ((DataTable)this.dataGrid.DataSource).Rows.Count;
int columnCount = ((DataTable)this.dataGrid.DataSource).Columns.Count;

((DataTable)this.dataGrid.DataSource).Columns.Count;
```

Second of all, what I want to add is that a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid` is a display widget control, and not a container for records. There is no `DataGrid.Rows.Count` property or something similar for finding out the number of columns. What you have to do is to look behind the DataGrid, at the `DataSource` property, which in most cases is a `DataTable` and take what information you need from there.