# Delete selected row from DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, rowdeleting

I need to delete the selected row from my DataGridView. Currently I managed to execute the select command but i do not know with what code to continue to remove/delete the selected row.

The code that i use is :

```
(refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vodic = '{0}'", searchTBoxW.Text);
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows)
{
    if (item.Visible)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        break;
    }
    //...
    //Other code
    //...
}
```

Where:
- refTofrPlanMain represents a reference to Form1 (I am working in Form2)
- dGVPlan is the DataGridView.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Biggest problem is you're doing a foreach loop and should never delete during a foreach loop. Better to reverse iterate and delete like here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: Thing is that i wil constantly search new values (the exact value will be filtered without doubles) and i want to delete it each time. Would that pose a problem ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though I'm not sure I understand your question. The only issue you may have is the larger your list gets, the longer the time it takes to iterate. But you were iterating it anyway, so I don't see an issue

Comment: My question is what is the code to remove the selected row, that would fit my code above.

Comment: Check the posted answer, not 100% `refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.Count` is how you access the row count, but should be something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Vodic = '{0}'", searchTBoxW.Text);
for(int i=refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.Count-1; i >=0; i--)
{
    DataGridViewRow item = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows[i];
    if (item.Visible && !item.IsCurrentRowDirty())
    {
        refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
    //...
    //Other code
    //...
}
```

Comment: It might be Items.Count, as referred to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838679/row-and-column-count-of-data-grid-in-c-sharp

Comment: It seems i recive a error : Additional information: Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted. Located at the and of refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.Rows.RemoveAt(i);

Comment: Should users be able to add new rows to your `datagridview` as it's complaining there is an incomplete row added?

Comment: Check the edit, added a IsCurrentRowDirty check:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentrowdirty(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, they do not add new row, it loads an .xls with OleDB. And i aim to remove from datagridview the rows.

Comment: You might want to set this to false then: `refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Comment: Solved the issue with the error, had to modify the GridViewProperty to AllowUserToAddRow to False. Thank you.